# Renderizando tabla con Jquery paginación

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola amigos estoy tratando de hacer una barra de paginación, pero solo consigo imprimir un solo elemento de la lista, alguien me puede decir que estoy haciendo mal?

```
        window.onload = function () {
            function setPagination() {

                var nextp = {{ current_page }} + 1;
            var prevp = {{ current_page }} - 1;

        var previos = document.getElementById("previous").setAttribute("href", "/projects/get-projects/" + prevp);
        var next = document.getElementById("next").setAttribute("href", "/projects/get-projects/" + nextp);

        var totalPages = {{total_pages}};


        if(totalPages > 5){


        }else{
            var divPageBar = document.getElementById("totalPages");
            for(var i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++){

                divPageBar.innerHTML = `<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">`+ i +`</a></li>`;

                    // <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
            };
        }



            };

        setPagination();
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que el problema radica en que estás sobre escribiendo el contenido de `divPageBar` cada vez que el for hace un recorrido, intenta cambiar el código de la siguiente manera:

```
window.onload = function () {
    function setPagination() {        
        var nextp = {{ current_page }} + 1;
        var prevp = {{ current_page }} - 1;

        var previos = document.getElementById("previous").setAttribute("href", "/projects/get-projects/" + prevp);
        var next = document.getElementById("next").setAttribute("href", "/projects/get-projects/" + nextp);
        var totalPages = {{total_pages}};

        if(totalPages > 5){

        }else{
            var divPageBar = document.getElementById("totalPages");
            let paginationLinks = '';
            for(var i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++){ //Vamos a llenar una variable con todos los li               
                paginationLinks += `<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">`+ i +`</a></li>`;
            };
            divPageBar.innerHTML = paginationLinks; //Ponemos todos los li en en el div
        }
    };
    setPagination();
};
```

Espero que funcione.